# What is the best way to profile javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, profiling

Is there a good profiler for javascript? I know that firebug has some support for profiling code. But I want to determine stats on a longer scale. 
Imagine you are building a lot of javascript code and you want to determine what are actually the bottlenecks in the code. At first I want to see profile stats of every javascript function and execution time. Next would be including DOM functions. This combined with actions that slows things down like operation on the rendering tree would be perfect. I think this would give a good impression if the performance is killed in my code, in DOM preparation or in updates to the rendering tree/visual.

Is there something close to what I want? Or what would be the best tool to achieve the most of what I've described? Would it be a self compiled browser plus javascript engine enhanced by profile functionality?

Comment: If `NODE_ENV=production node --prof app.js` won't do, see https://stackify.com/node-js-profilers/ or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for alternatives.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/docs.html)

Firebug provides a highly detailed profiling report.  It will tell you how long each method invocation takes in a giant (detailed) table.

```js
console.profile([title])
//also see
console.trace()
```

You need to call `console.profileEnd ()` to end your profile block. See the console API here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

## Blackbird

Blackbird also has a simpler profiler

- [Blackbird official site from Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509011712/http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/)
- [Source from Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blackbirdjs/)
- [Source from Github (pockata/blackbird-js: A fork of the cool Blackbird logging utility)](https://github.com/pockata/blackbird-js)
- [Source from Github (louisje/blackbirdjs: Blackbird offers a dead-simple way to log messages)](https://github.com/louisje/blackbirdjs)

Comment: I wrote that I know firefox. I want to have more stats from the browser that is influenting the execution of the javascript.

Comment: Ditto on Firebug, and you can profile straight from the console if you don't want to code it.

Comment: Firebug is just about the best tool you'll get.

Comment: Same thing works in the Safari Web Inspector

Comment: Firebug is good and all, but I can't believe there are so many people here chanting "Firebug, Firebug!" right after the OP said _explicitly_ that he wants to profile his code from multiple browsers.

Answer (score 22):

Chrome's Developer Tools has a built-in profiler.

Comment: +1, Speed Tracer is good, and it's important (as the OP mentioned) to profile your code in more than just Firefox to see how the individual browser affects it.

Answer (score 12):

Although Firebug has been mentioned, one additional thing you would want to look at with Firebug is a plugin for Firebug called [**FireUnit**](http://fireunit.org/); John Resig talks about it in this blog post:

> [**JavaScript Function Call Profiling**](http://ejohn.org/blog/function-call-profiling/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here seems to be download link - https://github.com/jeresig/fireunit/tree/master

Answer (score 4):

Firebug+Firefox is a must have.  And IE 8's developer toolbar also has a profiler built in (IE 8 ships with the developer toolbar).

Answer (score 4):

Safari 4's web inspector also includes a profiler (although the version in the nightlies is improved wrt. recursive function calls).  The Web Inspector also supports Firebug's profiler APIs.

Answer (score 4):

For JavaScript, XmlHttpRequest, DOM Access, Rendering Times and Network traffic for IE6, 7 & 8 you can use the FREE[dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com)

Comment: please, instruction how to install that as addon/extension in browser.