# Find out which functions use CPU intensively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using jQuery a lot, especially for animations like fading or sliding :)

so I'm attaching various functions that do this on elements like

`$(".fade").each(function(....)`

or

`$('*[class*="slide-"]').each(function(...)...`

On some elements I use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) without specifying a event (so it detects new elements that are being added in the DOM).

`$('*[class*="slide-"]').livequery(function(...`

This uses a lot CPU.

Anyway, what I'm asking is if there is a application or something, like a code profiler, that can show me how much CPU use each of these functions that are hooked on selectors/events.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the best way to profile javascript execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebKit based browsers (like Chrome) have cpu profiling tab in developer tools, might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Developer Tools in Chrome and Safari, or Firebug for Firefox, and check out the Profiles section. In IE8, press F12 to open its own developer tools and profiling. This question has also been [asked, answered, and accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution) already on stackoverflow.

Comment: +1 The only answer to cover multiple browsers and link to something.

Answer (score 3):

Firebug in Firefox has a wonderful profile tab that will show you scripts running and execution time (if that's what you're looking for)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, many modern browsers include profilers. You might also want to check out the jQuery Profile plugin as a complement to those profilers...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/profile

Answer (score 1):

The new IE9 beta developer toolbar has a nice profiler also.