# Performance profiling of ASP.NET MVC website code (including Javascript) for a specific user action on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, profiling, profiler

I have a ASP.NET MVC website and I would like to profile all the method calls (including Javascript) which get invoked on a specific user action on a web page (button click for example). I would like to know which methods are taking longer and/or called frequently, so that I can look into the issue. **I don't want to profile the whole website.**. The event is handled by the Javascript first which makes an Ajax call to the server, gets back the response and does something with it. There is a lot going on both on the client and on the server when this event fires, so looking for profiler to show the root cause of the problem, instead of manually debugging and stepping through every single method.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is http://miniprofiler.com/, it was originally developed for stack overflow if I understand correctly.

You can set the criteria (IP address, authentication, etc) for which to apply profiling on.

It doesn't look at client side profiling but then you can use firebug like another answer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tools that span both client scripting and server execution.  I would suggest [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for [profiling javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution) and something like [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) for the server-side.

It sounds like you are profiling for linear performance (just one user).  So, you want to first get some data to see if you want to focus on the client javascript or server, then drill in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use profiler shipped with VS. It could make Tier profiler, and you will get results of executing server-side methods, sql-queries, javascript used for generating response of each page.

Here is more about it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like DynaTrace is what you need but you'll also need $$$

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [UX Profiler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ux-profiler/pbggladnflcdnacpafmaahjemhnjmpjc). Its idea is to track and group all the browser events, network activity etc happening as a result of user action (click). It measures times of each activity and lets focus on the bottlenecks.