# How can I optimize a HTML5 + processing.js app?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, processing.js

I'm working in a HTML5 copy of a NES game ([link for reference](http://viclib.com/mememan)). It runs very well on my Macbook, but friends are reporting it is slow on their computers. I've done the optimizations that came to my mind, such as using a quadtree to select which objects to draw. Yet it seems like it's not enough and I just don't know where to work. How can I identify which specific parts of my app are causing the slowdowns?

Comment: Maybe this other question will help: [What is the best way to profile javascript execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution)

Answer (score 1):

For a real-time app like a game, I think Google Chrome Speed tracer would work very well.