# How can I benchmark JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

Is there a package that helps me benchmark JavaScript code? I'm not referring to Firebug and such tools.

I need to compare 2 different JavaScript functions that I have implemented. I'm very familiar with Perl's Benchmark ([Benchmark.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark)) module and I'm looking for something similar in JavaScript.

Has the emphasis on benchmarking JavaScript code gone overboard? Can I get away with timing just one run of the functions?

Comment: Seems to be a dup:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+profiler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)

Comment: I know it's not bulletproof and all, but related anyway : sometimes you just want to know [how to measure time taken by a function to execute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15641427/812102).

Comment: I good JavaScript benchmark tool can you find here: http://jsben.ch

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<del>Just time several iterations of each function. One iteration probably won't be enough, but (depending on how complex your functions are) somewhere closer to 100 or even 1,000 iterations should do the job.</del>

<del>Firebug also has a [profiler](http://getfirebug.com/js.html) if you want to see which parts of your function are slowing it down.</del>

**Edit:** To future readers, the below answer recommending JSPerf should be the correct answer. I would delete mine, but I can't because it has been selected by the OP. There is much more to benchmarking than just running many iterations, and JSPerf takes care of that for you.

Comment: Simply timing a pre-defined number of iterations of your code is [not bulletproof at all](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/). Also, having Firebug open disables Firefox’s Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler, which means the tests will be running in the interpreter, i.e. much slower than they would otherwise. Using Firebug’s profiler won’t give you the results you’d expect.

Comment: @Mathias: Well, to be fair, this answer is really old.

Comment: Sure, no offense mate. I just thought I’d comment for future reference now that more research has been done on the subject.

Comment: Or use http://jsben.ch since jsperf is down

Answer (score 144):

Just simple way.

```
console.time('test');
console.timeEnd('test');
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using a third party service sometimes is not convenient, and just using a simple built in feature is excellent.

Comment: @brainbag - The question was about benchmarking, which involves more than simply timing how long a bit of code runs.  Also, console timers are only useful if the code in question takes more than 1 millisecond (the limit of their resolution).

Comment: You may also want to run your benchmark in a test suite, which require to have access to the timer value.

Comment: The correct answer!

Answer (score 81):

Just adding a quick timer to the mix, which someone may find useful:

```
var timer = function(name) {
    var start = new Date();
    return {
        stop: function() {
            var end  = new Date();
            var time = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            console.log('Timer:', name, 'finished in', time, 'ms');
        }
    }
};
```

Ideally it would be placed in a class, and not used as a global like I did for example purposes above. Using it would be pretty simple:

```
var t = timer('Some label');
// code to benchmark
t.stop(); // prints the time elapsed to the js console
```

Comment: Good use of closures here.

Comment: For a more accurate result, one might want to use `performance.now()` instead of `Date()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Just what I needed - a timeIt()

Comment: TypeScript version: https://pastebin.com/gCs9CB5F

Comment: For node.js you can use [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.0/api/all.html#all_process_hrtime) to get nanosecond resolution.

Comment: You can also call `Date.now()` to get the current Unix Time instead of calling `new Date()` and then call `getTime()`

Answer (score 23):

I have been using this simple implementation of @musicfreaks answer. There are no features, but it is really easy to use. This `bench(function(){return 1/2;}, 10000, [], this)` will calculate 1/2 10,000 times.

```
/**
 * Figure out how long it takes for a method to execute.
 * 
 * @param {Function} method to test 
 * @param {number} iterations number of executions.
 * @param {Array} args to pass in. 
 * @param {T} context the context to call the method in.
 * @return {number} the time it took, in milliseconds to execute.
 */
var bench = function (method, iterations, args, context) {

    var time = 0;
    var timer = function (action) {
        var d = Date.now();
        if (time < 1 || action === 'start') {
            time = d;
            return 0;
        } else if (action === 'stop') {
            var t = d - time;
            time = 0;    
            return t;
        } else {
            return d - time;    
        }
    };

    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    timer('start');
    while (i < iterations) {
        result.push(method.apply(context, args));
        i++;
    }

    var execTime = timer('stop');

    if ( typeof console === "object") {
        console.log("Mean execution time was: ", execTime / iterations);
        console.log("Sum execution time was: ", execTime);
        console.log("Result of the method call was:", result[0]);
    }

    return execTime;  
};
```

Answer (score 9):

It’s really hard to write decent cross-browser benchmarks. Simply timing a pre-defined number of iterations of your code is [not bulletproof at all](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/).

As @broofa already suggested, check out [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/). It uses [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

if writing a custom benchmark script be sure to note that some browsers apply dom manipulations only after function in which they are defined is ended. More details here
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/08/when_to_read_ou.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need something simple you can do like this:

```
'use strict'
console.clear()

const powerOf = x => y => Math.pow(x, y)
const powerOfThree = powerOf(3)

function performanceCalc(fn, ...params) {
    const start = +new Date()
    const result = fn(...params)
    const end = +new Date()

    console.log(`Result: ${result}. Execution Time: ${end - start} ms`)
}

performanceCalc(powerOfThree, 2)
```

[Here is an example of the code](http://codepen.io/vlad-bezden/pen/YWJKkY?editors=0012)

Comment: Simple was definitely the best option in my case... writing some tests to benchmark response times for API (no need for extremely accurate times).