# I have two algorithms for fib problem, 1 is taking 7 milsec while other algorithm is taking 6 milsec even second algorithm is calling itself twice

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have two fib algorithm for comparison, one is mine while other is my teacher's,

1: Mine (taking 7 milsec)

```
function fibMineSolution(n, a = 0, b = 1, len = 1) {
    if (len === n) return b;

    return fib(n, b, a + b, ++len);
}
```

2: Teachers solution (taking 6 milsec):

```
function fibTeacherSolution(n: number) {
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

When I tested both as follow:

```
const t1 = new Date().getTime();
fibMineSolution(5);
const timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - t1; // gives 7...


const t1 = new Date().getTime();
fibTeacherSolution(5);
const timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - t1; // gives 6...
```

As you see, sir algorithm  is calling itself twice while mine is not! Also if I give larger value to mine function, It max call stack exeeds while sir algorithm doesn't has this issue,

By the way, I am new  to recursion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I benchmark JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003855/how-can-i-benchmark-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference for larger `n`, for example, `n = 100`. The first algorithm time complexity is `Theta(n)`, but the second one is `Theta(2^n)`. Hence, for `n = 100`, the first algorithm needs `100` recursion and comparison, but the second one needs near `2^100`!

Anyhow, for the small value of `n` you can see the difference, by running 30 times (for example) and compare the average running time.

Comment: sir which solution is faster ? mine or sir? mine math is so much weak!

Comment: @asdsad As I've explained, yours is faster.

Comment: But sir, when I tested my solution as follow: ` const t1 = new Date().getTime(); fib(5); console.log(new Date().getTime() - t1)  ` ,  it gave 7 milliseconds with my solution while 6 with sir's solution,

Comment: @asdsad I don't know if you read my answer or not, please test it for greater `n` to see the difference. For example, for `n = 50`.