# How to check and test how much memory a javascript app is leaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

iam looking for some tools or ways to detect memory leaks, slow methods in my javascript app.

Comment: Are memory leaks even possible in javascript?

Comment: @Sam `var i=""; while (1) { i+= "Are memory leaks even possible in javascript?";}` - not traditional memory leaks per se...

Comment: @sam absolutely.  bad use of closures can create memory leaks.  JS uses a mark and sweep GC, so keeping references to objects that should go away will cause a memory leak

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the profiler; I recommend Chrome's.  In the profiler the steps are

1. Go to the profile part of the developer tools
2. Get to the part where the slow js is
3. Start recording
4. Start the suspect code
5. Stop recording

After that, the profiler will tell you everything you want to know about how many objects there are, how much time is spent in each method, etc...

The procedure should be similar with Firebug on Firefox.

Comment: Is there any way to tell which methods are creating the objects that aren't GC?

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  Profilers/browser plugins are handy, but very well may yield results unique to the browser being tested on.  There are a number of techniques available from testing via multiple browser's plugins/profilers to inline debugging performance statements.

Two good articles with, robust examples and recommendations:

1. [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)
2. <s>[Memory leak patterns in JavaScript](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/)</s>