# How to determine which code is faster?

Tags: javascript, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)

I am currently trying to learn some JavaScript using js-assessment, which can be found here: https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment.

I have written the following code, which let's you find duplicates in an array:

```
function duplicatesInArray(arr) {
    var test;
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        test = arr[i];

        for (var j = i + 1 ; arr[j]; j++) {
            if(arr[j] === test) {
            res.push(arr[j]);
            break;
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Which works fine, but here's an anwser I've found on github (it works too):

```
function anotherDuplicatesInArray(arr) {
    var seen = {};
    var dupes = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        seen[arr[i]] = seen[arr[i]] ? seen[arr[i]] + 1 : 1;
    }

    for (var item in seen) {
        if (seen.hasOwnProperty(item) && seen[item] > 1) {
            dupes.push(item);
        }
    }

    return dupes;
}
```

My question is: how can I test which code is better?

Comment: Create a http://jsperf.com/ testcase.

Comment: Most probably the solution using an object will be slower, because object handling is hard work for JS engines. Arrays are easier. (Just my experience and opinion, not based on facts :D )

Comment: Here's the test case if someone is interested: [link](http://jsperf.com/duplicatetest)