# How can I calculate how much processing power a piece of javascript code uses?

Tags: javascript, processor

I would like to calculate how much processing power (in percentage, ideally) a certain piece of javascript code code uses. What are some known approaches I can use to calculate this?

Comment: have you tried this http://ajaxian.com/archives/jpu-javascript-cpu-monitor

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualise the CPU performance using Google Chrome Devl Tools

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en