# Improve performance while selecting element from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, checkbox

I have more than  20,000 records(rows) in my DOM. Each row has one checkbox and and textbox. When I check any checkbox its corresponding textbox should get disabled that's how logic works.

If Checkbox has id '1' then its corresponding textbox's id is 'text_1',the logic is 
**textbox's id ="text_"+checkbox_id**

Scenario : If I have list 10000 id's in random order (of checkboxes), I have to disable their corresponding textbox. My logic below

```
idList.each(function(id){
        $('#text'+id).attr("disabled",true).val("");
      }
    });
```

This logic takes around 10-12 sec to disabled all the textboxes.

Is there any way to improve performance.

Comment: `id` selector is quick then `class` but you should use `for` loop.

Comment: give them a class maybe and select all with that class and add the disabled attribute

Comment: your DOM  have same id's ?

Comment: Can you share HTML? and proper code rather than just couple of line of code

Comment: @ArunPJohny Best to provide as an answer.

Comment: are your records rendered on the browser?

Comment: @Suraj id inside each is index not html id attribute so its little bit unclear with your code.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by random, but is text box N in the same row as Id N?  If so going through the steps down/up the DOM might be faster than researching it completely.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal that was 10 times worse https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5vcu3zjx/3/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5vcu3zjx/5/ - but can try https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5vcu3zjx/6/

Comment: You can try https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5vcu3zjx/6/ - I still don't think it should take 10 second... the base test is getting over in 11 milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

Try this non-jQuery version:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).map(function(input){
    if(input.tagName == 'INPUT' && input.type == 'checkbox' && /^text_\d+$/.test(input.id))
    {
        input.disabled = 'disabled';
        input.value = '';
    }
});
```

It takes around 350ms - 400ms, on my computer, to disable 10000 checkboxes out of 20000 inputs, running Firefox 43.0.4.

Try it here:

```js
//Generate the inputs:
for(var i = 0, html = ''; i < 10000; i++)
 html += '<input type="checkbox" id="text_' + i + '"><input type="text" id="text_' + i + '_">';

document.body.innerHTML += html;


alert('Starting the test');

//Code to be tested comes here
var start = performance.now();

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).map(function(input){
 if(input.tagName == 'INPUT' && input.type == 'checkbox' && /^text_\d+$/.test(input.id))
 {
  input.disabled = 'disabled';
  input.value = '';
 }
});

var end = performance.now();

alert('Time: ' + (end - start) + 'ms');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select them by attribute value starting with using the `^=` operator:

```
 $('input[id^=text]').attr("disabled",true).val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a class and select all with that class and add the disabled attribute.

Give the text boxes a class then select them rather than looping

```
var thisClass = 'textBoxes'; //class for textboxes
$('.'+thisClass).attr('disabled',true);
```

To test it :

```
     function disableText(){
        var thisClass = 'textBoxes'; //class for textboxes
          $('.'+thisClass).attr('disabled',true);
    }; 

    var start = +new Date();  // log start timestamp
      console.log(start);

    disableText();//run your change here

    var end =  +new Date();  // log end timestamp
      console.log(end);

    var diff = end - start;
    console.log(diff);//this is the speed it ran at
```

Comment: can you please give demo for that?

Comment: @thisOneGuy you should make performance demo with time taken.

Comment: how can i test this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code

Comment: the second answer. Pass the current time to a variable, run the function, pass the new time to new variable and see the difference between the two

Comment: @thisOneGuy what do you mean by `function1` and `+new Date()`

Comment: put your logic in a function and call it after you log the start time and before you log the end time. the 'new Date()' gives you the time at that moment in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have made demo with time Difference in different statements `for`,`each` and `join` with `id-selector`. Check in browser `console`.

```js
var idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 91, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log("Each Loop");
var start = new Date().getTime();
$(idList).each(function(id) {
  $('#text' + id).attr("disabled", true).val("");
});
console.log((new Date().getTime() - start) +" ms" );

console.log("For Loop");
start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
  $('#text' + idList[i]).attr("disabled", true).val("");
}
console.log((new Date().getTime() - start) +" ms" );
console.log("Selector");
start = new Date().getTime();
$('#text' + idList.join(', #text')).prop("disabled", true).val("");
console.log((new Date().getTime() - start) +" ms" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="text1">
<input type="checkbox" id="text2">
<input type="checkbox" id="text3">
<input type="checkbox" id="text4">
<input type="checkbox" id="text5">
<input type="checkbox" id="text6">
<input type="checkbox" id="text7">
<input type="checkbox" id="text8">
<input type="checkbox" id="text9">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#tbl tr").find('td input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {

            $(this).closest('tr').find('#text_'+$(this).attr("id")+'').attr('disabled','disabled')

        });



    });




</script>
</head>
<body>
 <table style="width:100%" id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text_checkbox1"</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text_checkbox2"</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text_checkbox4"</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table> 


</body>
</html>
```