# Is there a more compact way to map values of specified keys, remove all the undefined values from the resultant array and get unique values from it

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, lodash

I have an object array:

```
var objects = [
  {'key1': '1', 'key2': '2'},
  {'key1': '3'},
  {'key1': '4', 'key2': '5', 'key3': '6'},
  {'key1': '1', 'key2': '2'},
  {'key1': '3'},
  {'key1': '4', 'key2': '5', 'key3': '6'},
];
```

I want an array with unique values of `key2` but without any `undefined` values in it. Something like this:

`['2', '5']`

**Right now, I'm using:**

`lodash.without(lodash.uniq(lodash.map(objects, 'key2')), undefined)`

**My Question:**

Is there a better and more compact way to do this?

Comment: if your code is working maybe it should go on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a use case I currently have. I won't be able to share the working code.

Comment: Compact is not always better

Comment: @YD1m that is such a throw away comment....

Comment: You could make it more readable using chaining: `let result = _.chain(objects).map('key2').uniq().without(undefined).value()`. Looks better when vertically stacked :)

Comment: @GruffBunny you can remove `lodash#chain` and then replace `lodash#without` with `lodash#compact`.  `_(objects).map('key2').uniq().compact().value()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objects.reduce(function(m,d){
    if(d.key2 != undefined && m.indexOf(d.key2)<0){
        m.push(d.key2)
    }
    return m;
},[])
```

Comment: How do we compare the performance of this approach against mine?

Comment: There are many ways to measure your code's performance. You can use profilers, log timestamps and on to more advanced options. You can start here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/measuring-javascript-functions-performance/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code

Comment: Great. That helps. Unlike Callum's comment that doesn't.

Comment: Hey Chirag, thanks. This is Infact, faster than my approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the object before making the values unique.

```js
var objects = [{ key1: '1', key2: '2' }, { key1: '3' }, { key1: '4', key2: '5', key3: '6' }, { key1: '1', key2: '2' }, { key1: '3' }, { key1: '4', key2: '5', key3: '6' }],
    unique = [...new Set(objects.filter(o => 'key2' in o).map(o => o.key2))];

console.log(unique);
```

ES5

```js
var objects = [{ key1: '1', key2: '2' }, { key1: '3' }, { key1: '4', key2: '5', key3: '6' }, { key1: '1', key2: '2' }, { key1: '3' }, { key1: '4', key2: '5', key3: '6' }],
    values = objects.reduce(function (r, o) {
        ('key2' in o) && (r[o.key2] = true);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
    unique = Object.keys(values);

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: I don't shure that ecma 2015 solution is suitable if pointed that lodash is used.

Comment: @YD1m why not? lodash also uses ES2015: [just one example](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseFlatten.js#L28)