# How to mask letters and numbers of a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following that works perfectly with numbers but I don't know how to get it to work with letters too.

```
var word = "4556364607935616";

function mask() {
  if (word.length <= 4) {
    return word;
  } else {
    var masked =
      word.substring(0, word.length - 4).replace(/\d/g, "#") +
      word.substring(word.length - 4, word.length);
    return masked;
  }
}
```

I'm guessing `\d` targets numbers? I'm not sure where to look for a reference guide for this kind of thing. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [A reference guide for this kind of thing.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is alter your regular expression slightly so that it works for letters as well. So, change `/\d/g` to `/[a-z\d]/gi`, where:

- `[a-z\d]` matches a character in the range of a to z as well as numbers and
- the `i` flag ensures that both lowercase and uppercase letters are matched.

**Snippet:**

```js
var word = "4f563a46jy7u35616";

function mask() {
  if (word.length <=4) {
    return word
  } else {
    var masked = word.substring(0, word.length - 4).replace(/[a-z\d]/gi,"#") + 
    word.substring(word.length - 4, word.length)
    return masked;
  }
}

console.log(mask(word));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I now know about the existence of the regex (I think it was touched on briefly on the beginner's course I'm doing) and so can now make sense of the symbols!

Comment: That's great @mistarsv. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: I did. My rep is too low though xD

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the vote count @mistarsv. You probably attempted to vote and that's why it didn't let you 

Answer (score 1):

The effective solution would be to not mask the string, but build a new string with provided length

```
var word = "4556364607935616";

function mask() {
  var LENGTH = 4
  var CHAR = '#'
  if (word.length <= LENGTH) {
    return word
  }
  var leftSideLength = word.length - LENGTH
  var result = ''
  while (leftSideLength--) result += CHAR
  return result + word.substring(word.length - 4, word.length)
}
```

Below the performance advantage shown

```js
var word = "4556364607935616";

function maskNotRegex() {
  var LENGTH = 4
  var CHAR = '#'
  if (word.length <= LENGTH) {
    return word
  }
  var leftSideLength = word.length - LENGTH
  var result = ''
  while (leftSideLength--) result += CHAR
  return result + word.substring(word.length - 4, word.length)
}

// Credit: Angel Politis's anwer on this Post
function maskRegex() {
  if (word.length <= 4) {
    return word
  } else {
    var masked = word.substring(0, word.length - 4).replace(/[a-z\d]/gi, "#") +
      word.substring(word.length - 4, word.length)
    return masked;
  }
}

// Performance test
// Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943511/2308005

var iterations = 1000000;
console.time('Using regex');
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  maskRegex(word);
};
console.timeEnd('Using regex')

console.time('Not using regex');
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  maskNotRegex(word);
};
console.timeEnd('Not using regex')
```

To get more info about regex performance, read [codinghorror post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/)

Answer (score 1):

**RegExp Reference Guide with Tutorials**: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

**RegExp Playground**: https://regexr.com/ (online tool to learn, build, & test regular expressions)

If you need to avoid replacing dashes `-` etc. use the word character `\w` (includes underscore):

```js
var word="abc-364-079-5616", masked=word.replace(/\w/g, "#"); //[a-zA-Z0-9_]
if(word.length > 4) {
  masked = masked.substring(0, word.length-4) + word.substring(word.length-4);
} else {
  masked = word;
}
console.log(masked); // "###-###-###-5616"
```

Here's how `masked` changes in the last example:

- `masked = "###-###-###-####"`
- `masked = "###-###-###-5616"`

**No RegExp Example**

Here's an example that doesn't use regular expressions (masks any character):

```js
var word = "abc6364607935616", masked = word; // word & masked are the same
if(word.length > 4) {
    masked = new Array(word.length - 4).join('#'); // create 4 less than word 
    masked += word.substring(word.length - 4); // add on 4 last characters
}
console.log(masked); // "###########5616"
```

Here's how `masked` changes in the last example:

- `masked = "abc6364607935616"`
- `masked = "############"`
- `masked = "############5616"`

Comment: Thanks! These are helpful links appreciate it.

Comment: @mistarsv An upvote would be great if I helped. Also, have you decided on which answer helped you the most?

Comment: I'm new to this site so my up-votes don't show! I used Angel's as it was most similar to mine. The others went a little too in depth for my purposes at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I got. You can use Regex pattern ([`\w(?=\w{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/hL4vY1/209)) to mask the last 4 letters like so:

```js
let word = "4f563a46jy7u35616";

function mask() {
  if (word.length <= 4) {
    return word;
  } else {
    return word.replace(/\w(?=\w{4})/g, "#");
  }
}

console.log(mask(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only end of the string and mask the remaining part, you could use this solution:

**Input** : "1234567890"

**Output** : #####67890

```js
const str = '1234567890'

const maskString = (string = '', maskCharacter = '#') => {
  const maskLength = string.length <= 10 ? string.length / 2 : string.length - 5
  return Array(Math.round(maskLength)).fill(maskCharacter).join('') + string.substring(maskLength)
}

console.log(maskString(str))
```