# Advisible to use === or !==?

Tags: javascript

Is it advisible to check for equality using === or !== operator in case of variables having only two possible values? What is the difference in terms of performance using these two comparison operators?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/111368/560648

Comment: Use one, test it, use the other, test it, compare...

Answer (score -2):

Use whatever makes the code more readable.

There's virtually no performance difference between `===` and `!==`.