# How to test performance / load of a modern angular application

Tags: angular, performance, testing, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to load / performance test a web application which uses angular 6+ as the frontend-framework. The application is quite big and uses lots of wizards / modals etc. 
I want to do some "real" e2e-frontend-tests (not just testing API-calls, but also js-rendering etc.)

What are the current state-of-the-art approaches and tools to test applications like this?

To clearify, i want to do some real e2e performance tests like e.g. open a browser in headless mode, open a wizard and get the time it takes until the wizard appears. Like frontend testing with selenium. I could do this with selenium too but i don't know if its the right tool.

Comment: How do you "load" a front end? Do you need to have multiple people using the same keyboard and mouse ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)

Comment: This seems to be a fairly broad and ill defined question as the application sounds like something with lots of moving parts which would affect load and performance testing. There is everything from the back end of database engine and database design to how much JavaScript is being used and moved about. This is the kind of thing that people write entire books about as well as design training about.

Comment: @richard chambers: to clearify, i want to do some real e2e performance test like e.g. open a browser in headless mode, open a wizard and getvthevtimevit takes until the wizard appears. Like frontend testing with selenium. I could do this with selenium toobut i don't know if its the right tool.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind is that because Angular applications are executed on the client's machine (unless you're using Universal for the first render), performance is going to vary quite a bit depending on processor, RAM, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way of testing client-side performance is profiling the application using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

If you want to automate the process - you should go for the browser automation framework, the most popular one is [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). You will be also capable of executing [JavaScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) calls to access [Performance object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) in general and [Navigation Timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) / [User Timing APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API) in particular.

I would also recommend keeping in mind server-side performance, i.e. you might want to check how many concurrent users you application can handle without issues, what are the saturation point / first bottleneck, when response time starts increasing or errors start occurring. So consider combining client-side performance tests with conducting the anticipated load onto your application as it can be the case that from client perspective rendering is very fast but server responds slowly causing bad user experience. Depending on your test lab hardware you can either go for [Selenium Grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) to kick off many browser instances or go for a [dedicated load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can not truly stress test your application using only UI browser testing, 
ideally, you would like to do both stress test all your application API calls,  while also running UI/browser test.

One option to consider could be [endly e2e runner](http://github.com/viant/endly/), it can do both of these tasks, load test and run selenium test in parallel

It may look like the following, where "data" folder contains previously recorded http requests with optional desired validation rules hiting your API

@test.yaml

```
defaults:
  target:
    URL: ssh://127.0.0.1/
    credentials: localhost
pipeline:
  init:
    action: selenium:start
    version: 3.4.0
    port: 8085
    sdk: jdk
    sdkVersion: 1.8

  test:
    multiAction: true
    stressTest:
      action: run
      request: @load_test
      async: true
    testUI:
      action: selenium:run
      browser: firefox
      remoteSelenium:
        URL: http://127.0.0.1:8085
      commands:
        - get(http://play.golang.org/?simple=1)
        - (#code).clear
        - (#code).sendKeys(package main

          import "fmt"

          func main() {
          fmt.Println("Hello Endly!")
          }
          )
        - (#run).click
        - command: output = (#output).text
          exit: $output.Text:/Endly/
          sleepTimeMs: 1000
          repeat: 10
        - close
      expect:
        output:
          Text: /Hello Endly!/
```

where @load_test.yaml

```
init
  testEndpoint: rest.myapp.com
pipeline:
  test:
    data:
      []Requests: '@data/*request.json'
    range: '1..1'
    template:
      info:
        action: print
        message: starting load testing
      load:
        action: 'http/runner:load'
        threadCount: 3
        '@repeat': 100000
        requests: $data.Requests
      load-info:
        action: print
        message: 'QPS: $load.QPS: Response: min: $load.MinResponseTimeInMs ms, avg: $load.AvgResponseTimeInMs ms max: $load.MaxResponseTimeInMs ms'
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I am endly author