# Angular simple performance testing

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests

My question is quite easy but google did not grant me the results i wanted.
I have an angular application which is only available in our network. I want to test the perfomance before and after a certain changeset.

What i want is something to load my application on a certain page (maybe login before that but i can disable login for testing purposes) wait for it till its painted and measure how long that took. Do that a 1000+ times and give me back the average time and maybe some other details.

Important is that the browser cache is empty every test otherwise tests results will be useless.
It is a full stack test so front + backend both combined load times is the result i want.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test performance / load of a modern angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405954/how-to-test-performance-load-of-a-modern-angular-application)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not really, that thread is focussed on load testing, atm I don't care about how many users use it, just want a avg load time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

Comment: And [How to programmatically empty browser cache.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a selenium script which opens my webpage and used the window performance object to set a marker in my application to get a load time, do that x amount of times to get an average. [How to test performance / load of a modern angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405954/how-to-test-performance-load-of-a-modern-angular-application) This post as suggested helps a lot with this.

Answer (score 2):

These browser tools doesn't execute your web 1000+ times, but I personally use them and they help a lot: [LightHouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) and Google Chrome Performance tab.

Executed on this stackoverflow page:

### Performance tab

[image: Performance tab summary]

### LightHouse

[image: LightHouse performance]

It even tells you how to improve performance:
[image: Lighthouse suggestions]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, both work like acharm, never used them before but they are super handy, not exactly what I needed but great tip nontheless.