# How to (efficiently and clearly) generate a unique set of compound objects? Can this be done avoiding JSON.stringify/JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, unique

Recently, I had to remove duplicates from an array of objects that I retrieved from MongoDB. Here is how I made it work:

```js
let users = [{_id:"abc",name:"Bob"},{_id:"xyz",name:"Al"},{_id:"abc",name:"Bob"}];
let uniqueUsers = [...new Set(users.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)))].map(y => JSON.parse(y));

console.log(users)
console.log(uniqueUsers) //expected output : [{_id:"abc",name:"Bob"},{_id:"xyz",name:"Al"}]
```

But I am wondering, is it an efficient way of doing it? Can it be done more elegantly? I figured that using some of the new features of ES6 would be a good way. What do you think ?

Edit : Since my objects are MongoDB documents, their ID is unique.

Comment: As the entries are an array of objects, using a set here does not really remove the duplicates, as each object points to a different reference

Comment: @Sushanth-- he's using JSON.stringify, so it will not use reference, but string comparison.

Comment: My bad, skipped over `stringify`, but still it is brittle as all the entries should be in the same format.

Comment: @user2864740 I mostly found old topics on that subject (before ES6) and I wondered if there were new ways that I had not seen that could solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @MohammadUsman No, that does **not** answer the question. Include such as a reference link, not an vote-to-close.

Comment: Yes using JSON as the identity of an object is really  expensive. There are lots of ways to do it making this question too open ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have `_id` on each object, is probably easier to get a unique set for those and map them

```
[...new Set(users.map(user => user._id))].map( id => users.find(user => user._id === id) )
```

Or you could `reduce` it based on `_id`

```
const reducedUsers = users.reduce( (acc, user) => { 
 acc[user._id] = user
 return acc
}, {} )

Object.values(reducedUsers)
```

Comment: At first, it seemed to me that you way of filtering by id and then using find() to recreate the whole object was not efficient. Actually, I was wrong, it's the best so far. I've compared using `console.time()` as suggested in a link in comments. Sometimes, even up to **10x** quicker than my original time. Thanks !

Comment: JSON.parse and JSON.stringify are eating a lot of cycles, that's most likely why it takes so long.