# performance.now() is undefined even though node is above 8.5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm trying to measure how much time it takes for a promise to resolve. However, I'm getting a "perfomance' is not defined" error even though I have node 15+.
Ive also tried putting in

> `const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');`

in my code but no luck.

I'm doing this in React, but I doubt that is making a difference.

Comment: You can use [`console.time()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)

Answer (score 2):

> I have node 15+

> I'm doing this in React, but I doubt that is making a difference.

React runs client side.

You might use Node.js to transpile JSX and modern JS into a lower level of JS that can be understood by browsers, but the program ends up running in the browser and not on Node.js (unless you are also using server-side rendering, but then you need to carefully differentiate what can run only server- or client-side).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code) addresses a number of ways to performance test code in the browser.