# creating a calendar in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am in the middle of creating a calendar in javascript but am contemplating using the date functions to retrieve values or splitting the date string to retrieve values. I tried looking up the big o for these functions but have not found any. I want to know what is fastest.

For example

```
var date = new Date();
date.toString().split(" ")[1]; //this will get month name
```

vs

```
var date = new Date();
date.getMonth() //this will get month
```

they might not be the same but my question is which one is faster.
edit i forgot toString.

Comment: I guess that spliting a string is faster but probably sure that the getMonth() method does the same internally

Comment: [Why don't you test it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)?

Comment: I will thank you for sharing

Comment: JavaScript's `Date` doesn't have a `.split()` method.

Comment: new Date() returns a date string with some information. I am just comparing getting the values there by splitting the string VS using the date functions to get the same values.

Comment: sorry i mean date.toString().split(" ")[number] ...

Answer (score 1):

As the split() method use searching by pattern algorithm and returns an Array
which is f(n) = n = O(n) [Big O notation] it is good performance wise.

But Date.prototype.getMonth() involve no searching and return the Number of the month – 1 as it starts counting at 0. (Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getMonth)  f(n) = n = O(1).

Conclusion : Date.getMonth is faster in time and space complexity then .split() method

Answer (score 0):

I would use the getMount() method  , it's a built in the object so it's more reasonable to me to use it along with all the other methods .
When you say "faster" you mean write less code or the code execution is faster?

Comment: I mean execution but thank you for your response. I will look at this.