# Which is more faster? trim() or RegEx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, high-load

Let's imagine that we have a string we want to check on validity.

Valid string is a string which have at least one non-whitespace symbol and which in not fully whitespaced. (i mean something like 5 whitespaces in a row and nothing else).

I have a two choices to check string validity: use a string.trim() method or use a custom regular expression for that.

I write a very performance dependent application, where every ms is can be a high cost.

So, the question itself: which is faster? regex or string.trim()

Comment: Are you doing like a million `.trim()` actions on a button click? If not, who cares?

Comment: Maybe go start with [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111368/1427878) ...

Comment: [If only there was a way to test this](https://jsbench.me/1xkw559809/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Test:

```js
var string = '    fsajdf asdfjosa fjoiawejf oawjfoei jaosdjfsdjfo sfjos 2324234 sdf safjao j o        sdlfks dflks l      '

string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, '')

string.trim()
```

### Results:

| Function | Result |
| --- | --- |
| regex | regex x 1,458,388 ops/sec ±2.11% (62 runs sampled) |
| trim | trim x 7,530,342 ops/sec ±1.22% (62 runs sampled) |

### Conclusion:

`trim` is faster

### Source:

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4767/0/regex-removing-whitespace-vs-trim